# Spaceship Adventures

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

As your starship cruises through the expanse of space, you receive a message from a dear old friend.

> My dear friend,
>
> A sylvan heir forced us to a-long paint. (t, w) I find sun cloth in your protected shirt. (s, s) A ship with slandering perception to gratuitously kick is on a sheep sheet. (l, f, r)
>
> Finally, pair up and search for the triplet. Meet me in that sector number.
>
> Best,
> Commander X

What is trying to be said here? Why all the secrecy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A TREASON (sylvan heir = tree son) forced us to WITHDRAW (a-long paint = with draw). I find SOLACE (sun cloth = sol lace) in your SAFETY (protected shirt = safe tee). A ship with LICENSE (slandering perception = lie sense) to FREEBOOT* (gratuitously kick = free boot) is on a RAMPAGE (sheep sheet = ram page).
>
>  There's an odd number of words, so maybe "pair them up and look for the triplet" means we should be grouping the words somehow. Two of the words have 6 letters, two have 8 letters, but three have 7 letters. That means we're meeting at sector 7?
>
>  * (Thanks to M Oehm)

Comment: Could [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freeboot) be the F word?

Comment: @MOehm Nice! I wasn't familiar with that word. I was only looking for words with "fri-" for some reason...